# How to generate gif from avi using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract a part of a video into an animated gif using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -t 5 out.gif
```

It generates an animated gif but the quality is insane. However when I generate gif image using:

`ffmpeg -i video.avi -t 10 out%d.gif`

It generates acceptable quality of gif images. How can i generate animated gif using the first command but the same quality as the second command?

Comment: This might be handy http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html

Answer (score 67):

I had a similar problem trying to generate high quality animated gif from a series of images extracted from a movie.

For some reasons the animated gif generated with ffmpeg only contains 103 colors assumable  using a fixed 256 level system color palette resulting in horrific result. My solution was instead

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -t 10 out%02d.gif
```

then

```
gifsicle --delay=10 --loop *.gif > anim.gif
```

Quality is then quite good. You can find gifsicle [here](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/)

**Edit:** Updated the post to reflect Alex Kahn's suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! One adustment: use out%02d.gif. This pads the number in the filename so that they are in proper alphabetical order. Otherwise the order ends up being 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22,23... which gives the resulting gif a weird skipping effect.

Comment: You could also have `ffmpeg` output PNGs instead of GIFs to avoid the crappy quality. FWIW, here’s a nice write-up on creating GIFS in Bash: http://blog.room208.org/post/48793543478

Comment: This works great. One thing you might also want to do, is to skip frames: using `seq -f %02g.gif start skip stop` instead of `*.gif` in the gifsicle command, you can skip `skip` frames, starting at `start` and ending at `stop` frames. Pretty useful.

E.g.:

    gifsicle --delay=10 --loop `seq -f %02g.gif 1 3 156` > anim.gif

Will start at frame 1, skip 3 frames and stop at frame 156.

Comment: in addition I suggest the next step: convert -layers Optimize anim.gif anim_opt.gif

Comment: `gifsicle` looks not working at all. says "gifsicle.EXE: *.gif: Invalid argument" in response to your command

Comment: for smaller GIF file size, you can adjust the fps, for example (5FPS): `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=fps=5 out%04d.gif; gifsicle --delay=20 --loop out*.gif > anim.gif; rm out*.gif;`
In the case of ffmpeg, if you specify lower FPS the number of files will be reduced. In the case of gifsicle, you need to delay further to compensate the missing frames. gifscile uses a scale of 1/100sec, which 20/100 means 5FPS.

Comment: Protip: `gifsicle -O3` optimizes gifs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made an animated GIF before but you might try using the bit-rate parameter to specify quality, in spite of it being an image (and presumably having no rate).  Thumbnail quality responds to the -b parameter.  If by insane, you mean, "insanely bad," you can specify a very high bitrate and bitrate tolerance (not sure if you're using vbr or cbr source).  (or do the opposite if you mean it's too good and you want to limit size)

`'-b', '10000000','-bt', '20000000'`

Alternatively, you could also change the dimensions using the -s parameter, which will take an ordinary looking representation of the dimensions like "1920X1200".

It really depends on the bitrate and compression of your source material and what you hope the gif will be like.  Maybe consider providing more info than "insane," but I imagine this will give you a good start either way.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I found out that ffmpeg is not really good at handling gif images so I used it to extract images but then use imagemagick to generate the gif.

Comment: Not sure why I'm receiving lots of downvotes here.  I stated up front I hadn't made animated gifs.  Was trying to point the person with the question to other relevant parameters.  The old FFMPEG project seemed to glory in having hidden many of its parameters outside of the docs.  Maybe I'm getting downvoted for revealing its terrible, dark secrets?